# Run Does not Work

Tags: external-calls, run

Hi  I would like to use the terminal code OCR softwar, called: Tesseract Optical Character Recognition (OCR)

Here you have a nice description of how to set it up: http://chillyfacts.com/convert-image-to-text-using-cmd-prompt/

Now my question is:

When I type: `"C:\OCR\tesseract" "C:\Image_to_OCR.jpg" "C:\out"` in the cmd command line, it works...

But when I try to run it from Mathematica:

```
Run["\"C:\\OCR\\tesseract\" \"C:\\Image_to_OCR.jpg \" \"C:\\out\""]
```

it does not work and returns "1" .

Any idea why or how I can fix it ? Anyone ?

Comment: Contrary to `Run`, `Import["! <<command line code here>>", "Text"]` works for me. Maybe you want to give it a try. Is is also capable of returning the error message and not only the error code (IRRC, you have to append `"2>&1"` to the command line code for that...)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you for your comment. Someohow it does not work for me :(. Maybe I am pasting a wrong command line. Can you show me how you typed your command line ? (I have Mathematica 11.3)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher This is what I typed: Import["!\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract\" \
\"C:\\Image_to_OCR.jpg \" \"C:\\Users\\James\\Desktop\\out5.txt\"" <> 
  "2>&1", "Text"]

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I get no error, but no file is created either

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It still does not work :( I also tryied it Mathematica 11.01 no change

Comment: Well, I work on macOS. I am afraid, I cannot help you any further with that. But probably some else with a Windows machine knows what to do.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Okay, thanks anyway !

Comment: Mathematica actually uses Tesseract under the hood somewhere and has a library, `TesseractTools` to help with that (found in `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Links`. I wonder if there's a way to do what you're looking for built-in.

Comment: You could try [RunProcess](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html). I.e. `RunProcess[{"C:\\OCR\\tesseract", "C:\\Image_to_OCR.jpg", "C:\\out"}]`

Comment: @ChrisDegnen I tryied it: I get the following error: Program RunProcess[{"C:\\OCR\\tesseract", "C:\\Image_to_OCR.jpg" not found.  Check Environment["PATH"]

Comment: I have a silly question: what happens if you just try `Run["C:\\OCR\\tesseract"]` without any of the arguments? I assume it's an error, but I'm curious which one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Files

Let's create some test files

```
Table[
 Export[
  StringTemplate["Test``.jpg"][k],
  Rasterize@TextCell[
    RandomChoice[DictionaryLookup["*"]],
    RandomChoice[{"Text", "Subsection", "Section", "Title"}]
    ]
  ]
 , {k, 10}
 ]
```

### [`RunProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html)

Test a single file using [`RunProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html) (advisable).

```
RunProcess[
 {
  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe",
  "Test1.jpg",
  "Test1"
  }
 ]
(* <|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> "", 
 "StandardError" -> 
  "Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica

  "|> *)
```

### [`Run`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Run.html)

Test a single file using [`Run`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Run.html), notice the extra quotation marks go only around the long path name to protect the spaces. Arguments do not need quotation marks.

```
Run[
  "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe\" Test1.jpg Test1"
 ]
 (* 0 *)
```

### Processing many files

```
Table[
 {
  StringTemplate["Test``.jpg"][k],
  RunProcess[
    {
     "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe",
     StringTemplate["Test``.jpg"][k],
     StringTemplate["Test``"][k]
     }
    ]["ExitCode"]
  }
 , {k, 10}
 ]
```

### [`TextRecognize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextRecognize.html)

Compare with Mathematica's [`TextRecognize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextRecognize.html)

```
TableForm[
 Table[
  {
   StringTemplate["Test``.jpg"][k],
   Import[StringTemplate["Test``.jpg"][k]],
   Import[StringTemplate["Test``.txt"][k], "String"],
   TextRecognize[StringTemplate["Test``.jpg"][k]]
   }
  , {k, 10}
  ]
 , TableHeadings -> {Automatic, {"File Name", "Image", "Tesseract", 
    "Mathematica\nTextRecognize" }}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice comparison: they are both terrible?

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot ! This is a really nice answer, and it works now ! :)

Comment: Do you have any suggestion of a  terminal-input program, which would deliver better results ?

Comment: @james I can only speculate, but I think the poor performance here is because there is no extra dictionary information and no grammar context. I have no suggestions for better OCR software.

Comment: I see. No worries. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @rhermans How can I run terminal commands from within a Mathematica notebook in Linux? If I run `Run["cd flagser"]; Run["./flagser input.txt --out output.txt"]` in MMA, nothing happens (the commands return 0 and 32256 in MMA), but if I run it from the console/CMD/terminal, a file output.txt is created, which contains the results of the calculation. Btw, I am using the software https://github.com/luetge/flagser.